# Laravel - withCount returns error saying SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'cars_count' not supported (forward reference in item list)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

By running:

```
$users = User::with('cars')->when(isset($data['cars']), function($query) use ($data) {
    $query->withCount(['cars' => function($query2) use ($data) {
        $query2->having('cars_count', $data['cars']);
    }]);
})->paginate(10);
```

What Laravel does:

```
select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `cars` where `users`.`id` = `cars`.`user_id` having `cars_count` = 32) as `cars_count` from `users` limit 10 offset 100
```

I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'cars_count' not supported (forward reference in item list)
```

What I want it to do:

```
select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `cars` where `users`.`id` = `cars`.`user_id`) as `cars_count` from `users` having `cars_count` = 32 limit 10 offset 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allows me to match your desired query.  I show it below using `->toSql()` on the builder instance.

```php
$users = User::with('cars')->when(isset($data['cars']), function($query) use ($data) {
    $query
        ->withCount('cars')
        ->having('cars_count', $data['cars']);
})->paginate(10);
```

Output (no pagination on mine)

```sql
mine:  select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `cars` where `users`.`id` = `cars`.`user_id`) as `cars_count` from `users` having `cars_count` = ?
yours: select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `cars` where `users`.`id` = `cars`.`user_id`) as `cars_count` from `users` having `cars_count` = 32 limit 10 offset 100
```

**EDIT**

I am adding a link to a package that is supposed to allow paginations with `having`,as it does not appear this is possible by default in Laravel.
https://github.com/justbetter/laravel-pagination-with-havings

Comment: returned SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cars_count' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` having `cars_count` = 32)

Comment: It seems to have to do with the pagination.  Run it without and see that you get a response.

Comment: Added a link to a package that should let you use paginations with `having`.

Comment: You made my day @matticustard :)